# I cannot upload 2 times the same image in the blobstore

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, file-upload, blobstore

I use GWT + GAE (JAVA).
I also use the blostore and the GWT file uploader (com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FileUpload).
Technically, the file uploader is inside a form. And I do not know if the error is more related to the GWT fileUploader or to the blobstore...

Here is the scenario :
0) I ask an URL to the blobstore (for example, I receive the URL http://example.url.blobstore).
This URL is used for the action form.

ACTION 1: (successfull)
A) I click on the fileUpload button
B) I choose the image "batman.jpg" and click OK
C) Then I send my form to `http://example.url2.blobstore` and the blobstore successfully save my image
D) I ask a new URL to the blobstore (cf. step 0)

ACTION 2: (fail)
A) I click again on the file upload button
B) I choose again "batman.jpg"
C) I cannot see the image loading in the preview...so I deduce that I cannot load 2 times the same image.
D) I **rename** my file in "**batman_1.jpg**" and I load it via the file uploader.
E) Then I can submit my form, and my image is saved.
G) I ask a new URL to the blobstore (cf. step 0)

I have to change the name of the image, or I have to refresh my page to upload this image again.
I do not know how to solve this issue, it is painfull to change the image name 10 times if I need to use it at 10 differents places in my application.

Thanks you,

Comment: To get a better response you'll have to stick to one question per question..! So I would suggest you to remove the second part and ask that in a separate question (for the quality).. and as for the first part you'll have to provide more info.. there are plenty of different ways of uploading things on app engine and you should also provide the language that you're using!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the issue with :

```
fileUpload.getElement().setPropertyString("value", "");
```

Comment: It is almost two years - But could you please post the code to upload the image and save it as a blob key ? I am stuck on this for quite long :/

Answer (score 1):

Did you create a new Form element? it is possible the Form cannot do a post twice with the same data. Maybe it's a browser optimisation for persons who double click on the submit button.

It's just a supposition, but try recreating the form widget onSuccess or even hide the form onSubmit (actually onClick is better) and show another form to the user